# How to pre-set zoom to 50% in asp.net RadEditor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radeditor

I am working on a web project in asp.net / vb using the Telerik RadEditor. The Rad Editor will be set to preview mode only but I would like the radeditor to be set at zoom level of 50%. (The radeditor will contain a html page containing marketing material which will be later exported and needs to kept at its original size).

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **fire()** method of the editor (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-fire.html) and its OnClientLoad event (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-onclientload.html):

```
        function OnClientLoad(sender, args) {
                sender.fire("Zoom", {value: "50%"});
            }
```

and here is how to attach it

```
        <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad">
            <Content>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </Content>
        </telerik:RadEditor>
```